# Download pdf with Angular v1.5 from a Slim v2.6.1 service

Tags: php, angularjs, pdf, download, slim

I am trying to download a pdf with Angular v1.5 from a service developed with Slim v2.6.1.

After downloading the file, I open it but it has not content, the pages are blank. 
I don't know why the source file size is 87 KB and the downloaded file is 135 KB.

The service code developed with Slim framework is :

```
$app->get('/pdfReport', function () use ($app) {

  try {
    $path = "./Service/reports/report_test.pdf";
    $app->response->setStatus(200);
    $app->response()->header('Content-Type','application/pdf' );
    $app->response()->header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'Binary');
    $app->response()->header('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename="report_test"');
    $app->response()->header('Content-Length', filesize($path));
    $app->response()->header('Expires', '0');
    $app->response()->header('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    $app->response()->header('Pragma', 'public');

    ob_clean();
    ob_start();
    readfile($path);
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    $app->response()->body($content);

  } catch (Exception $e) {
    $arr = array('status' => "error", 'fault' => $e->getMessage());
 }
});
```

In Angular the code is:

```
vm.generateReport = function() {
   var uri = "api/pdfReport";
   $http.get(uri, header).success(function(data) {
         var data = new Blob([data], { type: "application/pdf" });
         saveAs(data, 'Report.pdf');
    });        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When downloading binary data such as PDF or images, it is important to set responseType:

```
vm.generateReport = function() {
   var uri = "api/pdfReport";
   var config = { responseType: 'blob' };
   $http.get(uri, config).then(function(response) {
         ̶v̶a̶r̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶ ̶=̶ ̶n̶e̶w̶ ̶B̶l̶o̶b̶(̶[̶d̶a̶t̶a̶]̶,̶ ̶{̶ ̶t̶y̶p̶e̶:̶ ̶"̶a̶p̶p̶l̶i̶c̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶/̶p̶d̶f̶"̶ ̶}̶)̶;̶
         var data = response.data;
         saveAs(data, 'Report.pdf');
    });        
}
```

For more information, see [MDN Web API Reference - XHR responseType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType)